# standalone java program to decrypt password

Tags: encryption

I have to write a standalone java program to decrypt password from  file,using Symmetric key for password decryption.  I didn't work with encryption and decryption before. can anybody give any suggestion how can i do this.I need your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you need something like this

```
    private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
    ....
    ....
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(new String("here is your symmetric key").getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    //dencript mode (passes the key)
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    //Decode base64 to get bytes 
    byte[] encBytes  = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedValue);
    // Decrypt 
    byte[] plainTxtBytes  = c.doFinal(encBytes);
    // Decode
    String decryptedValue = new String(plainTxtBytes , "UTF-8");
```

Here are some resources:

1. http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/symmetric.shtml
2. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/EncryptionandDecryptionusingSymmetricKeys.htm
3. http://www.flexiprovider.de/examples/ExampleCrypt.html (This uses files as well)

Comment: Thanks your information is really helpful...but can you kindly describe the symmetric key part..

Comment: Symmetric-key algorithms are a class of algorithms for cryptography that use the same cryptographic keys for both encryption of plaintext and decryption of ciphertext. Therefore, if your key to encrypt the text is 'x' then also 'x' will be used to de-crypt the crypted message